# How to replace nested array value inside the Laravel request using merge?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-request

There is a function to replace the input from the request which is called merge.
I would like to change a value of a nested array so that it can be validated by `$this->validate method`..

This is the output of `$request->all()`

```
array:2 [
  "type" => "customer"
  "users" => array:1 [
      0 => array:3 [
        "name" => "eeee"
        "username" => "eeee"
        "password" => "123456"
      ]
  ]
]
```

How do I access the username value and change it, provided I use a forloop

```
for($i=0; $i < count($request->users); $i++){
    // i need to access the value here
    // i have done something like $request->merge(['users'][$index]['username'] => 'xxx');
    // it doesnt work
 }
```

Any solution guys?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this using merge method:

```
$new_users_data = $request->input('users');

foreach ($new_user_data as &$user_data) {
    $user_data['username'] = 'new name';
}

$request->merge([
    'users' => $new_users_data,
]);
```

You can also replace whole input with new one with request [replace method](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_replace).

Comment: Yeah, i forgot about pass by reference