# Laravel merge field in sub-arrays in the request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-request

I am receiving this data from the request:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "from" => 0
    "to" => 5
    "earned" => 0
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "from" => 5
    "to" => 10
    "earned" => 1
  ]
]
```

**I would like to add brand_id to each sub-array.**

I know that I can merge a field into the request like:

```
$request->merge([
    'brand_id' => $brand_id,
]);
```

Which results in:

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "from" => 0
    "to" => 5
    "earned" => 0
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "from" => 5
    "to" => 10
    "earned" => 1
  ]
  "brand_id" => "1"
]
```

Where I want the result to be:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:4 [
    "from" => 0
    "to" => 5
    "earned" => 0
    "brand_id" => "1"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [
    "from" => 5
    "to" => 10
    "earned" => 1
    "brand_id" => "1"
  ]
]
```

It would be nice if it was possible to do it like:

```
$request->merge([
    '*.brand_id' => $brand_id,
]);
```

Note: I have checked this [How to replace nested array value inside the Laravel request using merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257068/how-to-replace-nested-array-value-inside-the-laravel-request-using-merge) but if I'm going to use foreach, I won't need to be doing request merge. Besides maybe there's something new with Laravel 8.

Comment: @JustCarty Well, not exactly, I have already explained in the note below the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code. You can iterate each elements and merge. (assuming you are using a request object)

```
$mergedArray = array_map(function($element) use ($brand_id){ 
    return array_merge($element, ['brand_id' => $brand_id]); 
}, $request->all())
```

Comment: This is a nifty solution, I am applying it but I got an error: `Undefined variable: brand_id` Then I add `$brand_id` in anonymous function definition, this time got this error: `Too few arguments to function App\\Http\\Controllers\\ShiftBreakController::App\\Http\\Controllers\\{closure}(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected`. Searching for usage of array_map this way.

Comment: Found right usage here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599767/array-map-and-pass-2-arguments-to-the-mapped-function-array-map-argument-3 and got `$brand_id` variable like `function($element) use ($brand_id)` If there is no better suggestion I will mark your answer accepted @Kenath

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the use. I'll correct it now.